# rxjs or RxJS what's in the casing?

Tags: angular, rxjs

This warning pops up recently in my angular project..

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/RxJS/Subscriber.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
```

This warning is repeated for other .js files mentioned below..

```
node_modules/RxJS/InnerSubscriber.js
node_modules/RxJS/Observable.js
node_modules/RxJS/Observer.js
node_modules/RxJS/OuterSubscriber.js
node_modules/RxJS/Subscriber.js
```

and so on...

I do have the module imports that differ in casing in my `.ts` files as follows..

```
import { forkJoin } from 'RxJS/observable/forkJoin';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators'; 
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
```

I found that these warnings are gone if i changed the references of `RxJS -> to rxjs` (note the casing) in my `.ts` files as follows..

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin';
```

But want to understand what is the significance in changing the letter casing that got rid of the warnings and also, want to know whether i am going in the right direction and referencing the right things by changing the casing.

Comment: The package's name is `rxjs` not `RxJS`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/RxJS effects a 404 error.